# How do I change class static variables?

Tags: python, class, variables, static

I wish to define a dictionary which instances of the class can add entries to, and the class can add entries to. The example generates a 'TypeError: 'property' object does not support item assignment', when the class modifies the variable. How can I change myClass such that it passes the test below?

```
class myClass(object):
    _d = {} 

    @property
    def d(self):
        return self._d
    @d.setter
    def d(self,key,val):
        self._d[key] = val 


    def printMyClass(self): 
        print self._d 

A = myClass()
B = myClass()

A.d['a'] = 1
B.d['b'] = 2
A.printMyClass()
B.printMyClass()     # returns {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
myClass.d['c'] = 3   # fails, expect {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
B.printMyClass()
```

Comment: Change `myClass.d['c'] = 3` to `myClass._d['c'] = 3`?

Comment: doing print myClass.d makes printMyClass(self) returning <property object at 0x1004dd4c8>. How do I get it to return {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}?

Comment: You'll want `__repr__` and/or `__str__` for that